# Stack Overflow Q & A format

Tags: support, answers, specific-answer, downvote-reason

I am new to Stack Overflow, and I would like to understand something that I think I have missed. Recently I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425329/javascript-variable-with-function-call-to-cshtml/30425574#30425574). It was down-voted and I don't understand why.

The question shows that the author doesn't understand the basic concepts of the technology used. I have explained in general why they didn't achieved their expectations, and point to an article that can explain some details.

But I didn't write any code snippet, as the result depends on the end goals, and this is their work, not mine. They should write working code and my role (as I understand it) is just to point them in the right direction and explain general things.

Sometimes there is a need to give a detailed explanation with a code (as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421379/mongodb-custom-collection-serializer/30421805#30421805)) but not always. I was very surprised when, additionally to the down-vote, a third developer commented that my answer was not clear.

So I would like to ask community, was the down-voter correct or not? I think this community is not for me if the main criterion is a working example, and people prefer to get ready code instead of generalizing their questions and getting generalized answers.

Comment: Start out to give properly formatted questions instead _walls of text_. There are _paragraphs_, _lists_, etc supported with the markup implementation of the SO engine.

Answer (score 5):

Example code isn't required, but it is often helpful.

The issue comes down to whether you're answering the question completely or just pointing the user in the right direction.

Try to make sure that you're giving a complete answer, not just a
"This is what's *really* causing the problem..."

There's nothing wrong with explaining the cause of the problem, but you should offer a solution to the problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the question really just can't be answered because the OP doesn't have sufficient knowledge, then the question can't be answered, and trying to answer it is inappropriate. You can write a comment explaining why, vote or flag to close, or even downvote (if you think that's appropriate for some reason).

If, on the other hand, the question *can* be answered, then you have to give a complete answer. A complete answer doesn't have to have a full working program, or even any code at all, but it should be more than just explaining "here's what you don't understand" and recommending a blog post. The help section on answering should be helpful here, as will looking over existing (upvoted) answers.

Sometimes, a question *could* be answered in principle, but it would be very hard to answer to do it justice with any reasonable effort. In that case, it's up to you whether to make an unreasonable effort, or just not answer it.

Comment: "unreasonable effort for answering" seems very much like closing as "too broad" applies... no guarantee it does though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sure, the last paragraph is just about the rare borderline cases. I've seen some questions where I honestly wasn't sure if the problem was too broad and needed to be closed, or I was just too lazy to answer it. Which I've solved by just doing neither and moving on; there are always more questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't *always* need to include a working example, but a code snippet is generally less ambiguous than prose describing how it should work (particularly as it seems that English is not your first language).

You should always be careful with off-network links, too, and ensure that **your answer stands alone** (see e.g. [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731)); the link should either be a supplement to what you wrote or have its content summarised in the answer, so it's no major loss if it is later inaccessible.

As it stands, your answer just describes vaguely what the problem might be then sends the OP off somewhere else to get any real understanding. It doesn't actually tell them what they've done wrong or how exactly they should go about fixing it. Indeed, you *already have a comment telling you as much*. The comment doesn't even ask for a code snippet as such, but notes that (emphasis mine):

> It would help if you gave an example of **how to fix the op's issue**

which your answer conspicuously lacks. This could take several forms, although (as I've already mentioned) a code snippet is often the clearest.